# Why do I need to add extra time for Coinbase Pro API to get a succesful transaction with Python cbpro library?

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am using the Python library posted on @Dan Paquin GitHub repository:
https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python
The library is very well written and useful. However, I noticed that if I want to place orders in a for loop I need to add time.sleep(1.0) which seems too much. Otherwise, I got an error when I am trying to check the status of the order with:

```
status = self.cb_pro_client.get_order(self.OrderID)
```

This error only happens in production, with the sandbox version I cannot reproduce the error. The error basically complaints about not getting anything from the .get_order method.

I do not know much about the details about the library, but I read that you can only make 10 requests per second per IP, and I was making far less than those requests. Any suggestions ?

I am using coinbase pro,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell what error you're getting but I suspect it's 404?
I'm using the Node.js implementation and I get the same problem.

This isn't a problem with the python or node implementations as they are simply `get` wrappers to the exchange api endpoint  `https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/orders/{order_id}`.

[Coinbase get order docs if you're interested](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getorder).

Sometimes the details are available right away, sometimes they aren't. I've tried throttling for 10 seconds and sometimes still get an error. My solution has been to put the order details in a while/try loop. The most I've seen it fail is 3 times in a row so far.

node psudocode:

```
buyResult = <place buy order>;
let done = false;
while(!done){
    try{
        orderDetails = <get order details>; 
        done = true; 
    }catch(e){
        <output: e.message + " ...waiting 3 seconds">
        <sleep for 3 seconds before trying again>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Travis, I was also thinking about a try-catch approach with a while. After reading the information I agree with you, it seems is due to a non-deterministic behavior of the exchange. since I am using Python I do not know if it returns a 500 error.

Comment: how would you not know. the response contains the error code does it not?

Comment: the python wrapper does not return the message. The only thing I got from get_order() is: {'message': 'NotFound'} which is not very useful. get_order() should return a dictionary. I noticed that buy order always return status': 'pending', so the way to check should be with get_order().

Comment: "not found" is 404. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Travis for the info; I did not know that. So the only way is with try /exception in Python..

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in the background at CB. I would assume once `create order` returns a result `get order` should work. I've only had this issue when trying to get the order results right after placing a MARKET order.  I have another process that checks the status of a LIMIT order several minutes later and it works fine 100% of the time so it would seem that CB needs time for `get order` to work. Either give it a lot of space or the try/catch/while seems to work too.

Comment: I agree with you, I’m seeing the problem is when I place market order. The problem is that I don’t know how many responses I can get for “status” sometime it returns “filled” others “cancelled” but I don’t know if there are other possibilities. If you get “canceled” the you could place the market order again, wait 0.5 secs and then check with “get_prser” until is “filled” that way should be easy but manual does not show all possibilities.

Comment: ah, so according to the docs (I didn't see this before) `If the order is canceled the response may have status code 404 if the order had no matches.` So it also seems to return `404 - not found` if the order is still valid but not filled as well. If that's the case the market order could take some time to fill during low volume. I don't see any other way to test for the unfilled order if it returns a not found status.

Comment: Thanks @Travis, I checked the documentation and I found that part too. Thanks! what threw me off is the "may have status code" it does not say it has, so there is a possibility to return another code. So, creating an appropriate workflow to handle the exceptions is not straight forward.